# find & sed (search and replace)

Tags: find, sed, osx

I'm using the following command on my mac:

```
$find . -name “*.java” -exec sed -i ’s/foo/bar/g’ {} \;
```

and it seems to have no effect.

I have two files in the directory that end in .java, which both have the foo text in them.  Am I missing something?

**EDIT :
Results from request of comments**

```
[aafghani-03:~/test amirafghani]$ find . -name "*.java" -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} \;
sed: 1: "./bar.java": invalid command code .
sed: 1: "./foo.java": invalid command code .
```

Comment: Is that exactly what you're running?  What if you remove the `-exec` and everything after it?  Does it print the names of the Java files?  (I'm worried that you're using smart quotes instead of ASCII quotes.)

Comment: Actually, that solves it, at least for me. Both double and single quotes should be substituted by `"` and `'`, respectively.

Comment: Smart(?) quotes! .. :)

Comment: What I pasted was exactly what I was running.  Can someone post an answer?

Comment: @AmirAfghani Does `find . -name "*.java" -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} \;` work for you? (copy and paste it to the terminal). If so, I think Mikel could post it as an answer.

Comment: Next time please post the error message you are seeing when you ask the question.  It will save time for everyone.

Comment: Sorry was at work when I posted this -- I agree Mikel

Answer (score 86, accepted):

First of all, make sure you're using regular ascii quotes like `"` and `'` (ascii codes `0x22` and `0x27`, respectively) in shell scripts, because the example in your post contains non-standard quote characters. If you look closely, they look a bit different. Most probably this is a copy-paste error from a rich text document format like Word, OOWriter, or even a browser window.

Since you're on a Mac, you most probably have the FreeBSD implementation of `sed`, in which case you have to write the command this way:

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec sed -i '' "s/foo/bar/g" {} +
```

(here using `+` instead of `\;` to avoid running one `sed` invocation per file).

Note that those quotes around `"s/foo/bar/g"` are necessary if `foo` or `bar` have spaces.

In the FreeBSD implementation of `sed` the `-i` flag needs an argument: the extension of a backup file. For example with `-i .bak` the command would backup `file1.txt` as `file1.txt.bak` first before performing the replacement in the original file. Using an empty argument `''` means to not use a backup file, which seems to be what you want.

The same thing in the GNU (or NetBSD, OpenBSD, busybox) implementation would be:

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec sed -i "s/foo/bar/g" {} +
```

Thank you [@bahamat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3309/bahamat) and [@Mikel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3169/mikel) and [@pieter-breed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/56496/pieter-breed) for improving my answer with your comments.

Comment: What do the curly braces do?

Comment: @ZaneHitchcox the curly braces are placeholders for the matched filename

Comment: what's the `+` do at the end?

Comment: @Anthony the `+` at the end terminates the list of arguments of the `-exec` option. It is required by the syntax of `-exec`.