# sed incorrect for multiple occurrences per line - ignoring global flag

Tags: sed

Iterating through files with a specific extension and changing all occurrences of a substring with `sed`. Sometimes there are multiple occurrences per line. This is the command:

```
find . -type f -name "*.js" -exec sed -i '' s,/.*/marlon/express,/usr/src/app,g {} +
```

Iterating through `js` files to replace all occurrences of that wildcareded substring with `/usr/src/app`.

This works great on lines with a single occurrence but with multiple it seems to mess it up. It turned this:

```
__cov_cMGKPxliNj_ByZm9tnD9jQ['/Users/willashworth/Documents/Pimberly/marlon/express/client/js/manifest.js'] = {"path":"/Users/willashworth/Documents/Pimberly/marlon/express/client/js/manifest.js","s":{},"b":{},"f":{},"fnMap":{},"statementMap":{},"branchMap":{}};
```

...to this:

```
__cov_cMGKPxliNj_ByZm9tnD9jQ['/usr/src/app/client/js/manifest.js","s":{},"b":{},"f":{},"fnMap":{},"statementMap":{},"branchMap":{}};
```

The command seemed to remove everything from `'] = {"path":"/Users/willashworth/Documents/Pimberly/marlon/express/client/js/manifest.js` which is the 2nd occurrence in that file.

The whole file is:

```
var __cov_cMGKPxliNj_ByZm9tnD9jQ = (Function('return this'))();
if (!__cov_cMGKPxliNj_ByZm9tnD9jQ.__coverage__) { __cov_cMGKPxliNj_ByZm9tnD9jQ.__coverage__ = {}; }
__cov_cMGKPxliNj_ByZm9tnD9jQ = __cov_cMGKPxliNj_ByZm9tnD9jQ.__coverage__;
if (!(__cov_cMGKPxliNj_ByZm9tnD9jQ['/Users/willashworth/Documents/Pimberly/marlon/express/client/js/manifest.js'])) { 
    __cov_cMGKPxliNj_ByZm9tnD9jQ['/Users/willashworth/Documents/Pimberly/marlon/express/client/js/manifest.js'] = {"path":"/Users/willashworth/Documents/Pimberly/marlon/express/client/js/manifest.js","s":{},"b":{},"f":{},"fnMap":{},"statementMap":{},"branchMap":{}};
}
__cov_cMGKPxliNj_ByZm9tnD9jQ = __cov_cMGKPxliNj_ByZm9tnD9jQ['/Users/willashworth/Documents/Pimberly/marlon/express/client/js/manifest.js'];
```

With the issue being on line 5

**EDIT**

I have built this command from this answer: [find & sed (search and replace)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36795/find-sed-search-and-replace)

Comment: I don't think it's "ignoring [the] global flag" - it's just applying `.*` greedily

Comment: @steeldriver ah that would make sense! Do you have any idea on how to rectify that? I am new to `sed`

Comment: what exactly do you want the `/.*/` to match? a single directory component, or something else?

Comment: @thrig the `/.*/` should match `/Users/willashworth/Documents/Pimberly/`. I am using a wildcard though instead of hardcoding as different users will have a different filepath but the `/marlon/express` will remain constant which is why I am trying to use that as a terminator to stop the greedy operator ripping through the rest of the line

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Used `find . -type f -name "*.js" -exec sed -i '' s,/[^]]*/marlon/express,/usr/src/app,g {} +`. The parentheses stops it from greedily ripping through the rest of the line.

Thanks to this answer for steering me in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685575/sed-regex-to-non-greedy-replace