# Stuck With Using find and sed to Replace String in Filenames

Tags: sed, find, replace

Following [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36795/find-sed-search-and-replace) as a reference, I'm able to run a `find` and `sed` command without it throwing an error, but the filenames remain unchanged.

Trying to strip **pronunciation_de_** from all mp3s in the current directory:

```
pronunciation_de_wählen.mp3
pronunciation_de_wange.mp3
pronunciation_de_weil.mp3
pronunciation_de_werden.mp3
pronunciation_de_zentrum.mp3
```

Before troubleshooting the command, here's a quick sanity check:
`find . -name "*.mp3"`
It returns all the mp3s in the current directory. Continuing on now that we know this part works...

`sed --version` returns **sed (GNU sed) 4.4**

I run `find . -name "*.mp3" -exec sed -i 's/pronunciation_de_//g' {} \;`

To make sure I'm fully understanding what's happening:

`find .` runs the **find** command in the current directory.
`-name "*.mp3"` returns any .mp3 filetypes.
`-exec` executes the next command you type.
`sed -i` The **-i** switch means work on the actual files, not a (temporary) copy.

For `'s/old_word/new_word/g'`:

- The **s** sets sed to substitute mode.
- **/old_word** is the word you want to replace.
- **/new_word** is the word you want to replace with. In my example it'll be blank.
- **/g** apply the replacement to all matches (not just the first).

`{}` this string will be replaced by the filename during every iteration.
`\;` the semicolon terminates the **find** command. The backslash escapes the semicolon character in case the shell tries to interpret it literally.

Most of this information I'm getting from random blogs and Stack Exchange posts:

[Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find/389706)
[What is meaning of {} + in find's -exec command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195939/what-is-meaning-of-in-finds-exec-command)

I really wanted to take my time and experiment and research before posting this almost-certainly-duplicate question but I'm completely stuck!

Comment: sed does not rename files, it replaces text inside them; it is possible, but unlikely, that your MP3 files are now corrupted.

Comment: It's ok, I backed them up before experimenting.

Comment: Read `man rename` for what you are actually looking for

Comment: @Philippos dear god, I spent a few hours reading blogs and experimenting only to discover that what I was attempting was futile. Thanks for the tip. I read the man page and got it done in less than 20 seconds. Curious, in the first link I made in my post, some who commented reported it works for them.

Comment: Surely it did help them, because they are doing something completely different: They don't want to rename files, but change words inside of files. And for this purpose `find` with `exec` and `sed` is the perfect combination. (-: Glad I could help, anyhow.

Comment: @NomadicGoose, if you found a solution that works for you, consider writing it as an answer and accepting it so that the question doesn't get left "open". Or if another answer works for you, accept that instead, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find -exec ...` to do the replacement in a one-line shell script.

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/pronunciation_de_}"' bash {} \;
```

The filename `{}` is passed as parameter `$1` to the executed bash process and `${1/pronunciation_de_}` makes use of bash's parameter expansion capabilities and replaces 
the first occurrence of `pronunciation_de_` in `$1` with an empty string.

Additional option `-type f` makes sure to match only regular files.

Comment: You don't have to launch so many bash processes with: `-exec bash 'for file; do mv "$file" "${file%pronunciation_de_}"; done' bash {} +`

Comment: Note that if there is a subdirectory called, e.g., `pronunciation_de_files`, then this will remove the wrong substring from the pathnames.

Comment: @glennjackman The `%` in the parameter expansion in your comment removes a suffix string, not a prefix string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the `pronunciation_de_` prefix from all files with names that end in `.mp3`, then you should search for files with names matching `pronunciation_de_*.mp3` to be sure that you don't modify other filenames by mistake (however unlikely this may be).

Don't use line-oriented text-editing tools like `sed` on filenames. The shell knows how to delete prefix and suffix strings from filenames efficiently.

By using `find`, you could solve your issue with

```
find . -type f -name 'pronunciation_de_*.mp3' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        newname=${pathname##*/}              # removes directory path, leaves filename
        newname=${newname#pronunciation_de_} # deletes the prefix string

        mv -i "$pathname" "${pathname%/*}/$newname"
    done' sh {} +
```

The `find` command generates pathnames of files that pass the `-type` and `-name` tests and gives these in batches to a short inline `sh -c` script.

This script iterates over the given pathnames, and for each pathname it creates a new name by

1. removing the initial directory path, turning a pathname like `./some/path/pronunciation_de_werden.mp3` into `pronunciation_de_werden.mp3`, and then
2. removing the prefix string `pronunciation_de_`, turning `pronunciation_de_werden.mp3` into `werden.mp3`.

The `mv` command renames the original file by moving it to the new name in the original directory (`${pathname%/*}` will expand to the original pathname's directory path).

Answer (score -1):

For batch operation, I prefer GNU parallel.

```
ls -1 *.mp3 |
  sed 's/pronunciation_de_//' |
  parallel mv pronunciation_de_{} {}
```

`sed` removed the `pronunciation_de_` in filenames.
Therefore `{}` will be like `wählen.mp3`, `wange.mp3`, ...

Comment: Or: `parallel mv {} {=s/pronunciation_de_//=} ::: *mp3`